# Does einsum or opt-einsum optimized path consider the dimension of tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, numpy-einsum

Suppose I have a tensor contraction
 `A[ab] B[bc] C[cd] -> ABC[ad]`
where tensors `A` and `B` are  `n*n` tensors and `C` is `n*m` tensor, and `n >> m`.

There are two contractions

```
A[ab] B[bc] -> AB[ac], scales n^3
AB[ac] C[cd] -> ABC[ad] scales n^2 m
```

and

```
B[bc] C[cd] -> BC[bd] scales n^2 m
A[ab] BC[bd] -> ABC[ad] scales n^2 m
```

Under the assumption  `n >> m`, the second contraction is faster.

My question is, does einsum's search, greedy or optimal, consider the dimension of tensors, e.g., the above example?

I checked
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/index.html
https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/path_finding.html
It is not obvious to me if the above case is considered. I tried a few cases using optimize="greedy". They go like the second pattern. I would like to know if the dimensions of individual tensors were considered.

Comment: Why don't you just experiment?  Just make a few sample arrays, try thr path, and do some timings.

Comment: I just tried a 1000/10 case.  Default `einsum` is very slow.  With `True` it times the same as `A@(B@C)`, which is also what `np.linalg.multi_dot` does.  `einsum_path` explains the reasoning.

Comment: Thank you very much for the testing. I tried optimize="greedy" in a few contractions, it goes like A@(B@C). I am wondering if it is always the case. Question edited.

Comment: Did you look at `np.einsum_path`?  It's evident from its display that the primary consideration is the dimensions - which order has the best 'scaling'.

Comment: `optimize=True` isn't always faster.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000417/numpy-einsum-gives-error-dimensions-in-operand-0-for-collapsing-index-q-dont - here's it's slower with just 2 arguments and many dimensions.  Unlike your case there's no order-of-evaluation to consider.