# Numpy einsum gives error: dimensions in operand 0 for collapsing index 'q' don't match (4 != 2)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the following using numpy's einsum:

```html
import numpy as np

tmp_ee = np.ones((2,4,4))
tmp_ij = np.ones((2,2,4,2,4,2))
print(tmp_ee.shape)
print(tmp_ij.shape)
np.einsum('naq,nnbpqp->nab', tmp_ee, tmp_ij, optimize=True)
```

However, I run into the following error:

ValueError: dimensions in operand 0 for collapsing index 'q' don't match (4 != 2)

If you look at my code above, the index 'q' has dimensions equal to 4 in both arrays. The other repeating indices also have consistent dimensions. Hence, I do not understand the cause of this error. In addition to this, when my second array temp_ij has dimensions of the form (2,2,3,3,3,3) or (2,2,1,1,1,1) or (2,2,2,2,2,2), i.e., (2,2,x,x,x,x) then the error above does not come up and the code runs smoothly. I tried to work around this by doing the operation in two steps using einsum, as follows:

```html
tmp_ee = np.ones((2,4,4))
tmp_ij = np.ones((2,2,4,2,4,2))
print(tmp_ee.shape)
print(tmp_ij.shape)
temp = np.einsum('naq,nnbrqp->nabrp', tmp_ee, tmp_ij, optimize=True)
np.einsum('nabpp->nab', temp, optimize = True)
```

This does *not* give an error like the code before did. This works fine and gives me the result. While this workaround appears to be working fine, it has slowed down my code significantly because I have to do this computation millions of times in my code. Is there an explanation for the error above?

Thanks!

Comment: It runs fine on my version 1.19.  Did you get a traceback, or just the error message?

Comment: This runs faster without `optimize` set.

Comment: I do not see an error message using 1.16.3.

Comment: @hpaulj @AlphaF20 I was running my code on version 1.14.3. I had tried upgrading numpy before posting my question but I was getting the message "requirement already satisfied". After I saw your comments, I dug a bit more and was able to upgrade to 1.19.5. The code I posted is working for me now. I also checked out the `optimize` tip, and it does run faster. Thank you!